# How to save Live photo in document directory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdocumentdirectory, phlivephoto

How can i save live photo in document directory after picked up from camera roll using photo library? I can get live photo using this method

```
[manager requestLivePhotoForAsset:asset 
targetSize:targetSize 
contentMode:contentMode 
options:option 
resultHandler:^(PHLivePhoto * _Nullable livePhoto, NSDictionary * 
_Nullable info) {

}];
```

But i need to save this PHLivePhoto in document directory.

Comment: Any idea about .. i am facing same issue

Answer (score -1):

I think u save mov and jpg in docuent directory.